# How to find multiple elements by tag or class at once

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to find_all tags with a list of conditions at once?

For example, in this HTML I would like to extract `<p>` tags and `<div data-type="b">` tags.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
        <p>aaa</p>
        <p>aaa</p>
        <p>aaa</p>
    <div>
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>bbb</p>
        <p>bbb</p>
        <p>bbb</p>
    </div>
    <div data-type="a">...</div>
    <div data-type="a">...</div>
    <div data-type="b">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

**Desired output**

```
<p>aaa</p>
<p>aaa</p>
<p>aaa</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>bbb</p>
<div data-type="a">...</div>
<div data-type="a">...</div>
```

Of course I could do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
p_tags = soup.find_all('p')
div_tags = soup.find_all('div', {"data-type": "a"})
```

But I would like to do something like:

```
p_and_div_tags = soup.find_all(['p', 'div_tag_with_attribute'])
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **BS4 4.7.1** or above you can use css selector.

**Code**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div>
    <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
        <p>aaa</p>
        <p>aaa</p>
        <p>aaa</p>
    <div>
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>bbb</p>
        <p>bbb</p>
        <p>bbb</p>
    </div>
    <div data-type="a">...</div>
    <div data-type="a">...</div>
    <div data-type="b">...</div>
    ...
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items=soup.select('p,div[data-type="a"]')
print(items)
```

**Output**:

```
[<p>aaa</p>, <p>aaa</p>, <p>aaa</p>, <p>bbb</p>, <p>bbb</p>, <p>bbb</p>, <div data-type="a">...</div>, <div data-type="a">...</div>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
def func(tag):
    return 'div' in tag.name and tag.has_attr('data-type')

soup.find_all(['p', func])
```

---

**output**

```
[<p>aaa</p>,
 <p>aaa</p>,
 <p>aaa</p>,
 <p>bbb</p>,
 <p>bbb</p>,
 <p>bbb</p>,
 <div data-type="a">...</div>,
 <div data-type="a">...</div>,
 <div data-type="b">...</div>]
```